# How to use ? (short help of multiple functions)

Tags: documentation, user-interface, information-function

I want to use `?` Command in multiple functiones to make a list of quick references for the most common mathematica commands and print it as pdf.
For example `? Plot` works well. 
But how can I print an inventory for more than one commands: for example I would like something like
`?/@ {List, Table, Apply, Map}`

the option `#&?/@ {List, Table, Apply, Map}` neither works.

What is the `FullForm` or `InputForm of ?` or `??`.

Answer (score 8):

`??` is the same as [`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html). `?Sin` is the same as `Information[Sin, LongForm -> False]`.

```
Information /@ {List, Table, Apply, Map}
```

[image]

I have found the following command very useful especially in the case of my own pacakages:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
?"Notation`*"
```

[image]
... where all the table elements are links, which open the information below the table.

This works, because the first argment of `Information` can be a `StringPattern`. In order to make such a clickable table for the functions of your choice, use `Alternatives`:

```
pattern = Alternatives @@ ToString /@ {List, Table, Apply, Map};
Information[Evaluate@pattern, LongForm -> False]
```

[image]

where I have just clicked on `Map`. The color is different from the other pictures, because it depends on the *Mathematica* version it seems. Note also, that it creates nice sections for different contexts. Thus you can easily generate a interactive notebook with documentation of your own packages, if you have nicely written up all `::usage` messages.

I am mentioning this, because you might be trying to implement something what already exists.

Comment: Thank you very much Johu. This is what I need.

Comment: You are welcome! Just do not forget to accept and up-vote what you find useful!